# Does auto linking completely replace manual steps (react native)?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

As an example say I'm installing react-native-video and am testing on Android device:
https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#Android-installation

I have react native 0.60+ so it supports auto link. Do I completely skip the manual Android steps? It touches many things such as:

- settings.gradle
- build.gradle
- gradle.properties
- MainApplication.java

Comment: You'd do what the documentation says. The react-native-video documentation says that you don't need to do the manual steps unless you're having trouble with linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to skip manual installation steps for react native video. If any other additional steps are required for any library for React Native version 0.60+, they mention it with proper description of different version of React Native.